# Can't run ARM binary built on ARM docker - applet not found

Tags: docker, arm, cpu-architecture, alpine-linux

I'm having issues with making my docker emulate different architecture.

I've followed this tutorial to the letter in order to be able to build multi-architecture images: https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-for-arm-on-linux/

My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM alpine AS builder
RUN apk add build-base
WORKDIR /home
COPY hello.c .
RUN gcc "-DARCH=\"`uname -a`\"" hello.c -o hello -fno-stack-protector -z execstack

FROM alpine

RUN apk add util-linux

WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=builder /home/hello .

ENTRYPOINT setarch `uname -m` -R ./hello 0000000000
```

where `hello.c` is the same as in the tutorial (simply prints `uname -a`).

It is built using the command

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t local/armv7 . --load
```

This all works perfectly, `uname` is correctly saying it is a armv7l. The problem comes when I try to compile something new inside the docker.

What I did was running the docker in interactive mode with `/bin/sh`, add binutils `apk add binutils`, write a file `test.s` with ARM assembly, and then tried to compile and run it, as such:

```
as -o test.o test.s
objcopy -O binary test.o test.bin
chmod +x test.bin
./test.bin
```

this should work, however doesn't, and breaks with error:
`test.bin: applet not found`

I'm very confused what is going on and was not able to find anything online.

Note: running `test.o` gives the same error

Comment: `applet not found` means there is no application on the path to run the file. Does your architecture support ARM? Have you seen [this](https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-for-arm-on-linux/) guide on compiling for ARM with Docker?

Comment: I did indeed, the one I posted is very similar to yours (pretty sure they copied it). What confuses me is whether the resulting docker is actually emulating ARM, or is some sort of strange hybrid due to the host (my computer) being x86. The uname of the docker gives the expected result (armv7l), so why can't it compile and run an ARM binary?

Comment: For future reference, I ended up using the image arm32v7/ubuntu instead, never managed to solve this problem